# What should Resource Group and Runtime Stack be set to in order for me to get a simple Bottle web application running on Azure from VS 2019?

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, bottle

When following the instructions on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publish-to-app-service-windows?view=vs-2019) page, step 3 under "Using a Subscription" says:

> Specify a name for the web app, leave Resource Group to "Create New",
> and choose Windows as the operating system.

The page I am looking at is:

[image]

Which one of the drop-down elements does step 3 above say I should select for Resource Group?

Also, step 3 says to choose Windows as the operating system.

[image]

But the radio button for Windows is only selectable if I choose Python 3.6, not 3.7 or 3.8.

But I have Python 3.7 installed on my local Windows 10 computer as shown below:

[image]

I have no idea what version of Python is installed on the Microsoft Azure Application server.  So I am confused what I need to select to get this simple Bottle web application to run correctly on the Microsoft Azure server.

Would appreciate your input.

Comment: Hi @user1068636, would you mind accept my answer if it helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question, considering not sure if the Resource Group existed is yours or not, you'd better choose the `create new` option here, and name it specificly:
[image]

Second question, about "But the radio button for Windows is only selectable if I choose Python 3.6, not 3.7 or 3.8." It's recommend to use Linux OS. You could refer to this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-django).

Finally, it seems you are very new with Azure App Service, you could find [a tutorial or look at the concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview) first.